# JFileChooser and RMI

Tags: java, file, rmi, remote-access, jfilechooser

i tried to build a FileChooser with java and RMI to browse the file system of a remote machine.

What I did until now is best shown in the following diagram. The `exists()` method-call is an example and all methods of `RemoteFileView`, `RemoteFileSystemView` and `RemoteFile` forward to the server.

[image]

In words:
I build a `RemoteFileView` (`extends FileView`), `RemoteFileSystemView` (`extends FileSystemView`) and a `RemoteFile` (`extends File`) and overrode all methods of the super-classes except `File.hashCode()` and `FileSystemView.createFileSystemRoot(File)` (this method is protected in `FileSystemView`). All overridden methods call methods on the RMI-Server where the `FileView`- and `FileSystemView` from the server call the server-methods (like the `JFileChooser` would do). I get the `FileView` and the `FileSystemView` on the server side from a dummy instantiated `JFileChooser`.

So now what the system does: 
- Start RMI-Server 
- Start RMI-Client 
- `JFileChooser` gets the `RemoteFileView` 
- `JFileChooser` gets the `RemoteFileSystemView` 
- `JFileChooser` gets all the `RemoteFiles` from the server and shows folders as well as files in the `JFileChooser`

So the behavior is good until now. And now the problem (where I can’t get rid of):
The initial view of the `JFileChooser` (client) shows all Files of the home directory of the server. I can (per button click) switch to the parent directory until the system root (on windows for example the system drive „C:\“ ). From there (or from everywhere else) I can double-click on a folder to jump into it as long as this path exists on the client-system but the shown files and folders are from the server. If the path doesn’t exist on the client I can’t jump into it and browse this folder. So if anyone knows this behavior please help (I appreciate any solution :) ).

So I decided to code an own mouse listener that recognize double-clicks on the `JFileChooser`. But if I double-click on a folder (in the `JFileChooser`) nothing happens. If I highlight a folder (via click) and then double-click somewhere in the `JFileChooser` (not in the File-View or a button) the listener recognize my double-click and jumps into the highlighted folder (hope this is clear enough).

I think the `FileView` (on the `JFileChooser`) lies over the `JFileChooser` and should get it’s own listeners. Or I forgot something to code out.

The RMI-interface holds all methods which are called from the `RemoteFileView`, `RemoteFileSystemView` and the `RemoteFile` and from the behavior of the system this should be ok.

I can of course poste some codes as well as more informations about the whole program. Posting all codes would be too much I guess.

EDIT:
As this question may be "too broad" the more concrete version (which may solve my problem): Which listener fires on double click a folder in the JFileChooser? Can this listener be removed or set?

EDIT2:
I saw in this question: [Repurposing JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870861/repurposing-jfilechooser) that the JFileChooser fires on `JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION` whenever a file is choosen by double click. So I implemented this code:

```java
fileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Some action");
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
      File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(file);
      fileChooser.rescanCurrentDirectory();
    }
  }
});
```

But unfortunately the action listener doesn't recognize any action inside the FileView (the component which shows the files) but does fire action events on button clicks (which I detected with the System.out..).

Comment: This all boils down to "you need to build a file-chooser from scratch" which would show all the files of a specific directory of the client, when used in your server. So, pass list of all the files and name of the parent directory of the client to imitate that on the server side. I think this is one of the possible ways!

Comment: I want to show and browse the file system of the server  (from the client side), not otherwise ;) I found some solutions on the internet (JFileChooser over RMI) where people say to build your own FileView, FileSystemView and File, which I did).

Comment: Does this mean that this question be closed as it has been solved by you?

Comment: Sorry, no! I did all the coding stuff the last week, most of the time trying to solve my problem (including research) but nothing helped me. Unfortunately my problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: Well, this question is purely a give-me-the-code-to-achieve-this type question! I'm voting to close this question as too broad. By the time, you can try along the line what I suggested in the first comment. And, ask only specific problems here. Good Luck with your project, :)

Comment: Well, thanks for the comments, that motivated me to search on stackoverflow a bit and I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870861/repurposing-jfilechooser . There is some kind of answer which I try later today! I'll give an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as I described above are the components and their mouse listeners. So first you have to get your components and then add the listeners to it. So in a `JFileChooser` we got a `JList` and a `JTable`. Both views can be switched by button klick. The `JList` holds the files as well as the `JTable`.

I found kind of solution here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1350166?start=0&tstart=0

So I used some codes from there and implemented my mouse listeners:

The Listener for the JList:

```java
JList<?> list = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JList.class, fileChooser, "Enabled", true);

MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

   if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && file != null) {
      if (e.getSource() == list) {
        // Do your stuff
        operateOnFile(file);
      } 
      else {
        // Default operation
      }
    }       
  }
};

list.addMouseListener(listener);
```

And the listener for the JTable:

```java
final Container filePane = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(sun.swing.FilePane.class, list);

filePane.addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
    JTable table = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JTable.class, fileChooser, "Enabled", true);
    if (table != null) {
      for (MouseListener l : table.getMouseListeners()) {
        if (l == listener) {
          return;
        }
      }          
      table.addMouseListener(listener);
    }
  }
});
```

With this solution I got the behavior I wanted.